# How to override Fullcalendars AutoScroller edgeThreshold and maxVelocity in a upgrade safe way

Tags: webpack, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar v5 resource view (resourceTimelineWeek) with 200-1500 resources and the page or container gets quite long. I have drag and drop enabled and I can drag and drop events fine in the calendar. The problem is that it takes long time to drag something from the top to the bottom or otherwise long distance because the dragging, even at max speed, is not fast.

I found out that if you fiddle with [AutoScroller](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/3b70e546faebc8453f3cd3bc2b1d7fa73f9a3327/packages/interaction/src/dnd/AutoScroller.ts) and its attribute `maxVelocity` it will make the dragging much faster. At the same time I wanted the dragging to start a bit sooner than 50px from the edge so I modified `edgeThreshold` as well and I have exactly what i want now.

The actual problem is that I don't know how to change these default values (50 and 300) in a way that the calendar source code is still upgrade-safe. Actually I don't even know how to change these at all since the calendar source code comes from npm and webpack just packages it. I was able to test this by modifying the webpack bundled js code.

Is there a way to hook somewhere here my own implementation of the AutoScroller class or something similar?

Comment: `with 200-1500 resources`...seems a bit excessive. No human can realistically parse that quantity of information on screen at once. It's not a good UX. Consider using some filtering to add/remove resources according to user selection.

Comment: point taken, however the problem exists also just with 19 resources

Comment: Ok. `I don't know how to change these default values (50 and 300) in a way that the calendar source code is still upgrade-safe` ...there isn't an API hook for this currently, so you can't modify it in a way which wouldn't be overwritten by an upgrade. You'd need to modify the fullCalendar source code (which is available on GitHub), transpile it again and link to your own custom version in your app rather than the package.

Comment: If you want there to be an option in fullCalendar's API for this, then [submit a feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features). and you could also consider contributing relevant code yourself, since it's open-source.